# Can fopen or fstream etc. destroy file by accident C/C++

Tags: c++, c, file, fopen, fclose

1. Let's say I have somewhere in my program a function that opens a file with `fopen` and then my program does something else (say, try to calculate something) and then it crashes, because of some Null pointer, or stack overflow, or segmentation fault etc. Is there any chance that this would destroy/mess up  the file I opened?
2. What if I opened it for writing. Would it then be even more dangerous?

Comment: If you open a file for writing, and the given file exists, its contents are destroyed anyway.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different languages.  The C++ has `ifstream` and C doesn't.  C++ has stream extraction operators that can be overloaded to read in instances of custom classes.

Comment: File contents destruction on open depends on how you open. w and w+  and the contents are gone. a, r+ a+ and the contents are still there.

Comment: Open file with different name (i.e. `FILENAME.tmp`), write to it and than rename it to original filename only if writing was successful

Comment: If I used "fopen" on file_1 then copied the content to a buffer (some RAM memory my programs has), then copied the memory to a new file file_1_copy and closed it, and THEN opened file_1 for writing, then would that be fully safe? In that even if my program crashed while copying the file to a copy-file, nothing would get lost, and if the program crashed while writing the original file, then the copy would provide a backup?

Comment: Back-up are a good idea. Just make sure the back-up succeeded before editing the original. Typically there are system functions you can use in place of copying the file yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you open a file for ***reading*** then **no**, you cannot corrupt a file.
2. If you open a file for ***writing*** then **yes**, it is always possible to leave the file in some corrupt state.

Comment: I guess I could very much depend on the OS. But yes, common sense says your answer is right.

Comment: Er, any OS/FS that makes your data vulnerable by simply _reading_ it is unusable. It’s not just common sense, it is required functionality.

Comment: On at least some platforms and filesystem types, reading a file will update some meta-data associated with the file -- notably timestamp information. So reading actually involves a write to some part of the filesystem. On Linux filesytems, so far as I know, the meta-data area in question is of a fixed size, and I don't think that a failed write can leave the file or directory defective. I've never seen it happen, anyway. But I don't think that it can safely by assumed that in all circumstance it is _impossible_ for a failure during read to leave the filesystem unhappy.

Comment: That is true, but keeping that atomic is the job of the OS, not your program. Some FSes are better designed to recover from things like <user turns off computer instead of shutting down>; FAT FSes, in particular, are vulnerable to corrupted sectors when user does that. This is an entirely different issue than a user program crashing, though...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and quite explanatory discussion guys.